# How to use 3rd party libraries in glassfish?

Tags: mongodb, glassfish, java-ee-6, glassfish-3

I need to connect to a MongoDB instance from my EJB3 application, running on glassfish 3.0.1. The Mongo project provides a set of drivers, and I'm able to use them in a standalone Java application.

How would I use them in a Java EE application? Or maybe better phrasing: how would I make a 3rd party library available to my application when it runs in an EJB container?

At the moment, I'm getting a java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError when deploying a bean that 
tries to import from the library:

```
[#|2010-03-24T11:42:15.164+0100|SEVERE|glassfishv3.0|global|_ThreadID=28;_ThreadName=Thread-1;|Class [ com/mongodb/DBObject ] not found. Error while loading [ class mvs.core.LocationCacheService ]|#]
[#|2010-03-24T11:42:15.164+0100|WARNING|glassfishv3.0|javax.enterprise.system.tools.deployment.org.glassfish.deployment.common|_ThreadID=28;_ThreadName=Thread-1;|Error in annotation processing: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/mongodb/DBObject|#]

[#|2010-03-24T11:42:15.259+0100|SEVERE|glassfishv3.0|javax.enterprise.system.core.com.sun.enterprise.v3.server|_ThreadID=28;_ThreadName=Thread-1;|Exception while loading the app
org.glassfish.deployment.common.DeploymentException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/mongodb/DBObject
at org.glassfish.weld.WeldDeployer.event(WeldDeployer.java:171)
at org.glassfish.kernel.event.EventsImpl.send(EventsImpl.java:125)
at org.glassfish.internal.data.ApplicationInfo.load(ApplicationInfo.java:224)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:338)
```

I tried adding it to the NetBeans project (Properties -> Libraries -> Compile -> Add Jar, enable 'Package'), and I also tried manually copying the jar file to $GF_HOME/glassfish/domains/domain1/lib (where the mysql-connector already resides).

Do I need to 'register' the library with the container? Reference it via Annotation? Extend the classpath of the container to include the library?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Hmm... Shouldn't you put this "driver" in `glassfishv3/glassfish/domains/domain1/lib/ext`?

Comment: @Pascal: thank you! I thought I had tried this, too. Anyway, works like a charm. Is that a good way though? Shouldn't this be part of the deployment?

Comment: @Hank I don't know how the MongoDB driver is used but if it isn't used by the container (like a JDBC driver would be to create a connection pool) nor shared between apps of the domain, then you should maybe package it inside your application.

Answer (score 9):

You could put shared libs to lib/ext of your domain. commons-logging and jdbc drivers are often added in this domain path.

> Common Class Loader
>
> GlassFish v2 has a well defined Class
>   Loader hierarchy which identifies the
>   common class loader as the proper way
>   to deal with shared libraries. So to
>   make a long story short, putting you
>   libraries and other framework JARs in
>   domains/domain1/lib is all you need to
>   do.
>
> lib/, not lib/ext
>
> The person asking me the question had
>   tried putting the libraries in
>   domains/domain1/lib/ext which
>   triggered an interesting
>   ClassNotFoundError for core Java EE
>   classes such as
>   javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet. Shing
>   Wai Chan was quick to explain that
>   domains/domain1/lib/ext is part of
>   -Djava.ext.dirs which makes any of its JARs be considered as a JDK extension
>   which means web app frameworks placed
>   there will be loaded before
>   webcontainer implementation classes as
>   they are higher up in the classloader
>   delegation chain.

Comment: Did you try the above with GlassFish v3?

Comment: will try glassfish3 asap but not yet :)

http://blogs.sun.com/alexismp/entry/glassfish_equivalent_to_websphere_s

Comment: This works with GlassFish v3/3.1 as well. I've put my PGSQL driver into glassfish/lib for my past few installations and it works without any additional configuration.

Answer (score 3):

Glassfish has own Class loader hierarchy, http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19798-01/821-1752/beade/index.html
I face the same problem in my project and then I put all my Third party libraries in domain/domain1/lib and my problem solved. On other way round, my problem was solved too by putting  libraries in glassfish/lib.

Answer (score 2):

In my case I was using Oracle Express Edition 11gR2 and Glassfish 3.1.2 and the ONLY way that works in my case was putting the ojdbc6 in:

```
C:\Program Files\glassfish-3.1.2.2\glassfish\lib
```

Answer (score 2):

1. Go to your Glassfish doamin directory.
2. Then go to lib folder.
3. Place the libraries there.
4. Restart the glassfish and run.

(Ex) C:\glassfish3\glassfish\domains\domain1\lib

Answer (score 0):

Try to put Your libs into $GF_HOME/glassfish/modules/.
It's dirty, but will work.