# Shared libraries between wars

Tags: java, libraries, shared

I use server glassfish and maven, I have many wars deploy and each one have their libraries. Many of them use same libraries and I want to extract this libraries out of the war. I try to put them in a folder /lib of the server and put provided scope on the dependency of the war, but this don't work fine because the server ask for more libraries and i have problem with other wars. Also I try with scope system but doesn´t work.

I was searching a solution in Internet and only find skinny wars.

¿There are a way to do it?

If I will create a ear with the commoms libraries could I referenced them from a war (or packaging the war in other ear)?

Thanks you very much.

Comment: Why do you want to do that? You're sacrificing the independance of your webapps to gain some megabytes on a server disk, which must have GBs of free space. As soon as you'll need to change the version of those shared libs in one of the webapp, you'll run into problems. JEE was designed like this for good reasons.

Comment: I have commons libraries that don´t change and I have a space problem on server.

Comment: I have 25 wars, many people work modifying them and it is imposible make and ear with all wars each time one changes.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, if you create an EAR and but the WAR libraries into it, they could reference any library in the EAR's lib folder.

Comment: Thanks for the quickly answers. I have 25 wars, many people work modifying them and it is imposible make and ear with all wars each time one changes.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you package your `.war` files into an `.ear` and add shared libraries to the `lib` of the EAR project?

Comment: Thanks for the quickly answers.

I have 25 wars, many people work modifying them and it is imposible make and ear with all wars each time one changes.

Comment: Ohh Then I suppose the only way to do it is to include them in the server's custom lib folder. I'm not familiar with glassfish hence cannot help you much! This might help http://stackoverflow.com/q/2507099/154325

Comment: I tried this but each common library need another library and I put them in /lib of server, finally I have too much libraries in server.