# Cannot connect to database using JDBC on Glassfish3

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, glassfish

Is there any way to check whether my Glassfish acctually see ojdbc6.jar ?

I'm working with Netbeans 7.2.1, with JSF 2, Glassfish 3.1.2 and Oracle 11g. I want to connecto to this database.

So first I need to create connection pool in my Glassfish. I open localhost:4848 set 5 things:

1. Resource Type: javax.sql.DataSource
2. Class name of the data source: oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource
3. Property: "user"
4. Property: "password"
5. Property: "url"

Save, reset server (just for sure), ping.... and the error: **Class name is wrong or classpath is not set for: oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource**

What have I already done:

1. First check for ojdbc jars. From my Oracle dir I copied every jar that has "ojdbc" in name into "C:\glassfish3\glassfish\domains\domain1\lib".
2. Second, check url properity. Inside Netbeans, switch into Services tab, right click on Databases, New connection... set data to connect (first I have to add, jodbc6.jar.. so I add exactly the same file - from glassfish folder). It works! connection is ok. I looked at Netbeans database url - the same as my url in glassfish gui. I also tried url with \, but it didn't help.

So, what else can it be? Maybe no.1 is not ok. So this is my question: **How can I check whether my Glassfish acctually see ojdbc6.jar?**

EDIT.
When I run Glassfish i get some warnings:

> WARNING: Multiple [2] JMX MBeanServer instances exist, we will use the
>   server at index [0] :
>   [com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.DynamicInterceptor@704d54].
>
> WARNING: JMX MBeanServer in use:
>   [com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.DynamicInterceptor@704d54] from index [0]
>
> WARNING: JMX MBeanServer in use:
>   [com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer@ed312d] from index [1]

Comment: The jar is obviously not loaded...

Comment: I think that this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2507099/how-to-use-3rd-party-libraries-in-glassfish might help you. Lookalike problem.

Comment: Copy all jars in "C:\glassfish3\glassfish\domains\domain1\lib\ext" ? I did it.. but didn't work:/

Maybe i need write sth to enviromental PATH ? Set sth in settings? Bu what?

Comment: Please look at EDIT in my question

Comment: Try to use these jars from simple public static void main(String[]){} program. If it works, then the problem is with jar attaching. If it doesn't, then its wrong jars or something like this.

Comment: here is the app: http://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-0112.html

Comment: I have created simple java application with code from that link and included all ojdbc jars into Libraries - it worked.. 

Where is the problem ? I have only one Glassfish dircetory on my machine.. How to make my Glassfish to see these jars ?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Copy all required jar files(ojdbc6.jar.....) to 'domains\domain1\lib\ext' folder. Then restart your glassfish.
Then try to ping from glassfish, it will work

Comment: well, it doesnt't. But how do you know it is 'ext' folder? And not just 'lib'? One guy says lib, other ext.. But where it is written that Glassfish is expecting these jars in ext dir.? A config file or sth like that.. This is foundamental question in that subject i think.. 

btw. "restart your glassfish". I do that via Netbeans IDE. Services tab, Servers, Glassfish, right-click and restart..

Comment: @Marshall To restart glashfish open command prompt goto bin folder of glassfish and type 'asadmin stop-domain domain1'  this will stop glassfish
then type 'asadmin start-domain domain1'. I am sure it will work

Comment: hey, I had to take a break on this project, but now I'm back and it works. Restart glassfish via cmd helped! Thanks!

Comment: I've got one more question. Should I every time start Glassfish via cmd before I Run my project ? What is wrong with Netbeans ?

Answer (score 2):

"..But how do you know it is 'ext' folder? And not just 'lib'? One guy says lib, other ext.."

> Making the JDBC Driver JAR Files Accessible To integrate the JDBC
>   driver into a GlassFish Server domain, copy the JAR files into  the
>   domain-dir/lib directory, then restart the server. This makes classes
>   accessible to  all applications or modules deployed on servers that
>   share the same configuration. For  more information about GlassFish
>   Server class loaders, see "Class Loaders" in GlassFish  Server Open
>   Source Edition Application Development Guide. If you are using an
>   Oracle database with EclipseLink extensions, copy the JAR files  into
>   the domain-dir/lib/ext directory, then restart the server. For
>   details, see "Oracle  Database Enhancements" in GlassFish Server Open
>   Source Edition Application  Development Guide

[From here](https://glassfish.java.net/docs/4.0/administration-guide.pdf)

Answer (score 1):

Note that when NetBeans runs glassfish on Windows, the "domains" directory it uses is in your home directory, not in `C:\glassfish` or `C:\Program Files\glassfish`

On my windows 7, running NetBeans 8.0.2 with Glassfish 4.1, I had to put the Oracle driver jar (ojdbc6.jar) into

```
c:/Users/t823517/AppData/Roaming/NetBeans/8.0.2/config/GF_4.1/domain1
```

Answer (score 0):

May be netbeans create virtual app if you run glassfish from IDE.
Try this way of adding jars: http://netbeans.org/kb/docs/javaee/entappclient.html

Comment: As I wrote in Fathah answer comment - it work, and it was netbeans somehow.. And right now, I'm not 100% sure where is the difference between starting Glassfish from IDE or cmd...

Answer (score 0):

Copy the ojdbc6-11.1.0.jar (the ojdbc6 version  could be different in your case ) to glassfish_installation\glassfish\lib

Restart glassfish server

Answer (score 0):

For payara  server  i copied  ojdbc jar to  {payara_installation_folder}\glassfish\lib,its works fine