# Morphia gives NoClassDefFoundError: com/mongodb/DBObject?

Tags: mongodb, morphia

I run Morphia 0.102 with the Mongo Java Client 2-11.2.

This is a client / server app. At the moment I test the server side locally on GlassFish.

Ok, when I run some code on the client, using Mongo and Morphia, no issue. Then when some code is called on the server side, it instantiates Morphia on the server with

```
        mongoClient = new MongoClient("199.00.000.000", 27017);
        morphia = new Morphia(); //exception thrown
```

The exception:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/mongodb/DBObject  
    at com.google.code.morphia.Morphia.<init>(Morphia.java:48)  
    at com.google.code.morphia.Morphia.<init>(Morphia.java:44)
```

I've spent several hours trying to change the versions of Morphia and the MongoDriver, with no result and I have no clue.

Any idea?

Comment: I have found the solution here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2507099/how-to-use-3rd-party-libraries-in-glassfish

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, adding the jar in the glassfish folder solved this exception when I was running GlassFish locally, from Netbeans. The issue came back when I uploaded my Java EE module on the server.
Adding the mongo and morphia jars in all kinds of folders did not solve anything then. The thing that solved it :
- I integrated my Java EE module into an EAR, then deployed the EAR (before that I was only deploying the Java EE Module without an EAR - surely a very bad practice, but I did not know).

Answer (score 2):

Are you including the morphia jar in your war file?  Adding things to that glassfish folder is almost always the wrong answer.

Comment: So, adding the jar in the glassfish folder solved this exception when I was running GlassFish locally, from Netbeans. The issue came back when I uploaded my EJB on the server. Adding the mongo and morphia jars in all kinds of folders did not solve anything then. Two things solved (I don't know if each separately would have sufficed):I integrated my EJB module into an EAR, and when deploying the EAR from the GlassFish console, I filled their name in the field asking to specify libraries (which is either specific to EAR deployments, or more probably that I missed it before).