# Glassfish and Java EE external JAR

Tags: java, postgresql, jar, glassfish

I am trying to use postgres on a EJB in a EAR, but i keep getting the error:

> java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.postgresql.driver

so my app is not finding the jar. According to what I saw here: [How to use 3rd party libraries in glassfish?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2507099/how-to-use-3rd-party-libraries-in-glassfish), I should put the jar on either `glassfish3/glassfish/domains/domain1/lib/ext` or `glassfishv3/glassfish/domains/domain1/lib`, I tried both and is not working.

I was also not sure of something, should I add the jar to that folder and then reference the build path (using netbeans) of my app to the jar on that folder? or should I omit this step?

Anyhow, I tried both, referencing it and not doing it (only adding the jar to the folder in glassfish) and is not working.

So, how can I add an external jar to my application (EAR) that is put on a glassfish cluster?

Comment: You should *not* use `lib/ext`, that's only appropriate if you want to override built-in modules. `lib` is correct. IIRC no further action is required in glassfish 3, but I last used it a few years ago. Are you certain it's in the correct domain?

Comment: The mistake was mine, it was actually `org.postgresql.Driver ` instead of `rg.postgresql.driver`, the tutorial I was using had it with d so I wouldn't suspect it was with D, I noticed it when I checked the source code of the lib I was using.